# merging social media profiles (Locality Sensitive Hashing)

Tags: social-networking, graph-algorithm, locality-sensitive-hash

Was wondering if anyone had any nice reading material regarding the topic which is pretty self explanatory what I want to do is create a program which is able to merge different social media profiles into one profile.

So for example if I have a twitter profile page, facebook profile page and a stackoverflow profile page I want to be able to create a program which say with certainty X the following 3/2 profiles from different social media networks are for the same person Y.

Thanks in advance
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

You can find very detailed explanation of LSH here: [Mining Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf)